# Are either $\pi + e$ or $\pi e$ transcendental if we add or multiply digit-wise?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, digits

Since $x^2 - (e + \pi)x + e \pi = (x - \pi)(x - e)$ has transcendental roots, we know that the coefficients are not both rational, and not even algebraic (*see [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333967/are-either-pi-e-or-pi-e-transcendental-if-we-add-or-multiply-digit-wise#comment833909_333967) by José*).

My question is, can we determine, by either adding or multiplying digit-wise (mod 10) the digits of $\pi$ and $e$, whether the resulting numbers are transcendental?

Suppose $p_n$ and $e_n$ are the $n$th digits of $\pi$ and $e$ respectively.  Let $d_n = p_n + e_n \ (\mbox{mod } 10)$.  The new number $t$ will have $d_n$ on the $n$th digit.  We can similarly define $t$ with $d_n = p_n \cdot e_n \ (\mbox{mod } 10)$.  Is $t$ transcendental?

More general version of the question:

Since it might be very difficult to determine whether two individual numbers are transcendental, here is a more general question:

If we add or multiply the digits of $\pi$ or $e$ digit-wise (mod $n$), where $n$ is a digit from 2-10, which of the resulting numbers are transcendental?

In the general case, define $d_n = p_n + e_n \ (\mbox{mod } k)$ where $k$ is an integer in $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.  In this case, we can use a choice function to determine $k$, or determine $k$ from $n$ in some suitable way.  In the general case there are many possibilities for the different kinds of numbers that can be formed.

Comment: If both of them were algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then both $\pi$ and $e$ would be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, q.e.a. Thus, one of those two numbers is of necessity transcendental.

Comment: Thanks Jose, yes I was thinking the same and corrected.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. There certainly does not exist a way to understand whether a number is transcendental, looking at a finite number of digits.

Comment: Daniil, I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm saying add or multiply from $\pi$ and $e$ at each digit and then find the resulting number mod $n$ at every digit to get a new decimal number with an infinite length.

Comment: I bet they're all transcendental, and I bet I won't be able to collect on my bet.

Comment: “Either” $\pi+e$ or $\pi e$ is transcendental whether the pope is catholic or I am the queen of England. What is the question?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: I believe the idea is to create two new operations, call them $+_{10}$ and $\times_{10}$, which come from identifying an element of $\mathbb{R}$ as a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, $x \mapsto (\dots, 0, 0, \dots, a_n, a_{n-1}, \dots, a_0, a_{-1}, \dots)$, via the decimal expansion, and adding or multiplying componentwise.  The question then is whether $\pi +_{10} e$ or $\pi \times_{10} e$ are (identified with) transcendental numbers.

Comment: Oooh! I see now. What about $\sqrt 2+_{10}\sqrt 3$, $\sqrt 2\times_{10}\sqrt 3$?

Comment: Nate, that is a great notation! I like your explanation.

Comment: Your question starts with someone else's explanation of your question in terms of two new operations $+_{10}$ and $\times_{10}$, and then immediately discusses the old operations $+$ and $\times$.  It seems very confusing to me.  I have inlined @NateEldredge's comment in favour of not forcing people to read a non-zoomable screenshot, but I left in the original screenshot too, since it seems necessary for understanding what you're saying.  I encourage you to replace the screenshot by the text if it is consistent with your intention.

Comment: LSpace, thanks I thought it would be helpful but I see it is not :)  I'll remove the image!

Comment: I edited the question, so I hope it is more clear. This is similar to another question I asked (though I had since deleted my account).

Comment: Even simpler questions seem impossible. Just take the digits of $\pi$ or $e$ and reduce them, say, modulo $2$. So $\pi = 3.1415926536... \mapsto 1.1011100110...$. Is it transcendental? Irrational?

Comment: Great idea Zach!

Comment: What does the preamble, which is about the usual sum $\pi+e$ and product $\pi e$, now have to do with the question about $\pi+_{10}e$ and $\pi\times_{10}e$?